# how to remove contend from div contend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want concept from your side. Actually I want to append some text when a user scrolls to the top of content(again and again). But I want to remove the text when the user goes to the bottom of the page.
I get the event at the top and bottom and I am able to prepend it, but I want to remove that content (prepend text "naveen").

http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/6/

```
$("#content").scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0){
         //alert("top");  
     $("#contend").prepend("naveen")   
    }
});


$("#content").scroll(function() {
    if (  document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
          $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight )
    { 
        // Display alert or whatever you want to do when you're 
        //   at the bottom of the page. 
        //alert("You're at the bottom of the page.");
    }
});


setInterval(function(){
$("#content").append("Random text to be appended here")



},2000);
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your English is very poor and that makes your post hard to understand.

Comment: Where you `prepend` your ,'naveen'.. unable to find ??

Comment: please check my fiddle

Comment: Actually I just want when user scroll bottom of page .if remove all "preappend " text if exit .Now preappend text is "naveen"

Comment: It's content my friend, not contend :)

It does make things harder to read.

Comment: Sorry can we do that ..If I preappend three time ,and when user goes to bottom of the page it remove all preappend text

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, add a span element into your div and put the prepend text into that span element (will make cleaning easier).

Then, your scroll at bottom test function was wrong.

HTML

```
<div id="contend"><span id="pre"></span></div>
```

JS

```
if ( $('#contend').scrollTop() >= $('#contend')[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight ) { 
    $("#pre").html('');
}
```

And of course, the prepended text goes into `#pre` instead of `#contend`: `$("#pre").prepend("naveen ");`

See it all here: http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/11/